# Calling a method from another method and passing parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core, methods

I have a method which I call via an `ajax` call and due to that, I cannot return a view. I thought maybe I can call another method and pass the values to the second one and then return a view.

```
public ActionResult Get(List<Models> model, string message)
        {
            // code shortened for brevity
            Save(model, message);
            return null;
        }
```

and then my second method would return a view

```
public ActionResult Save(List<Models> model, string message)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = String.Format(message);
            return View(model);
        }
```

This doesn't work. What should I return in the `Get` method? The model & string I am passing to the `Save` method are empty. Is this doable?

Comment: There was an almost identical question yesterday. First **don't** call one action from another. Extract the common code into a separate method. Actions specify routes, HTTP methods and validation rules. Calling one action from another mixes them up and instead of avoiding duplication, you get mixed up validation rules. *Second*, return whatever data you need from the new common method and return it as a view from your own action with `return View(thatData)`

Comment: `via an ajax call and due to that, I cannot return a view` you can still return data either by returning the data you want directly or using eg `Ok` or `CreatedAtAction` to return specific HTTP status codes. Check the `GetTodoItem` method in [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: `The model & string I am passing to the Save method are empty` what *do* you want to return then? A GET is meant to return something, not save or update. That's the job of `POST`

Comment: You crucified me there but honestly thanks. All your comments will be put to use :)